# yum install specific version of python package

Tags: pyside, centos7, yum, python-packaging

I want to yum install python-pyside, but I don't want any old/new version of pyside, I want pyside version 1.2.1.

How can I do this?

I currently have:

```
yum install python-pyside
```

Comment: Do a Yum search and [Yum Info command](https://cloudomelette.com/top-10-yum-commands-in-linux-with-examples/) which will provide a list of python package versions you can choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check which versions are available in your repos

```
yum --showduplicates list python-pyside | expand
```

Then use the following to install a specific version that is listed from the command above

```
yum install <package name>-<version info>
```

Which means if v1.2.1 is available, you would need to run the command:

```
yum install python-pyside-1.2.1
```

If it's not available then you need to enable a repo which has that version.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. How can I enable other repos?

Comment: Here is a good digital ocean article on the matter, which goes into better/more detail than I will be able to give you personally https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-yum-repositories-on-a-centos-6-vps